# Cannot access protected property JException::$code

Tags: joomla2.5

Fatal error: Cannot access protected property JException::$code in /.../templates/abrax/error.php on line 14

Lines 14-17:

```
if (($this->error->code) == '404') {
header('Location: http://www.example.com/404');
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use getters, you can't access property directly because it's visibility is not `public`

Like

```
if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
...
```

Comment: i face this same problem, and i changed the code as you said,but another error show to me: `Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context`
What's this mean?

Comment: @JackZhang how exactly did you write it, can you copy the line of error? did you put `=` instead of `==`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
if ($this->_error->get('code') == '404') {
header('Location: http://www.example.com/404');
exit;
}
```