# Joomla Upgrade from 3.3.6 to 3.4 ERROR: Invalid AJAX data

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

There is an error showed in a pop-up when I try to upgrade my 3.3.6 Joomla website:

ERROR:

> Invalid AJAX data: **Fatal error**: Cannot access protected
>   property JException::$code in
>   **/home/MYSITE/public_html/WEBSITE-FOLDER/templates/MY_index_template/error.php**
>   on line **14**

I guess there is 404 page url on line 14 :
(between line 13-17):

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
if (($this->error->code) == '404') {
header('Location: index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=90');
exit;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: [Cannot access protected property JException::$code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870170/cannot-access-protected-property-jexceptioncode)

So change

```
if (($this->error->code) == '404') {
```

To:

```
if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @liquidflo. But this time the error is : ERROR:
AJAX Loading Error:    It doesn't say anything else.

Comment: How are you upgrading your website? Did you try to upload those package files manually via FTP?

Comment: I generally use the easy button there inside the Joomla to upgrade it. But this time I even tried uploading everything via FTP and interstingly, nothing changed. It was my first time using FTP for this kind of thing but I tried it 2 times. Should I try it again? Maybe it would work with a new connection?

Comment: Did nothing change on the website? or did you get the same error

Comment: I've just tried it one more time. Within my FTP or Cpanel I can see the dates of some files and folders are changed regarding to my previous updloading. But the result is same. When I login to my Joomla backend it is still showing "Joomla! 3.4.0 is available" and the Update Button. It is still 3.3.6. Can it be somewhat related to Hosting?

Comment: Now I have cleared my cache on backend and also purged the expired ones but the result is still the same. Should I upload the package again via FTP?

Comment: It's worth trying but I have no idea why it's not working.. Normally it shows a error after AJAX Loading Error:

Comment: Yes! It's done now. After clearing the cache I uploaded everything via FTP and this time it worked. Now it is Joomla 3.4.0 . Thank you @liquidflo

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the WindowsHosting/websitefolder/tmp that was not allowing the files to be written. File name created but 0 bytes size.
SOLUTION:
I have ftp access, downloaded and uploaded the update package to that tmp folder and clicked on the update again. This time it ran successfully. 
Incidentally was going from 3.4.1 to 3.4.5